# Apple SignIn Delete Account Reregister

Tags: ios, apple-sign-in

Apple SignIn is designed in a way that you only receive the email-address and the users name during the initial signin / when you create an account. My App is running on a parse backend, so when a user signs in the first time I create a parse user and save the name and email to it. The user can delete the account in my app - when he does, I delete the parse user object which includes the id and the token, but also email and name. When a user decides to reregister, Apple assumes that he already has an account and only gives me the id and token, with which I can create a new parse user but I cannot get the email / name again. Is there any proper way to handle this issue?

Comment: Don't delete the user record, just flag it as deleted/inactive?

Comment: I think one should provide a possibility to the user to delete all his data

Comment: Your only other option is to return an error to the user explaining that they need to go into their Apple id settings and remove the association for your app since they have deleted their account.

Comment: Yeah fair point, that seems like a good idea, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to revoke the user token when the user deletes his account.

You can do it by using Apple API explained [here in Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sign_in_with_apple/revoke_tokens)

Once you do it, when a user deletes his account and sign in again, you will get his email and name, as if it is his first time login in your app!